# Java JPanel inside JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have a JFrame, in this JFrame I have a JPanel that I draw on, this Panel can be any size and so I placed it into a JScrollpane to let me scroll when the panel is larger than the window screen size.

Unfortunately does not work as I expected:

1. Making the JFrame window smaller than the JPanel size does not show scroll bars
2. The JScrollPane size now seems locked to the size of the JPanel I have added to it, where as before it resized to the bounds of it's JFrame window (it still kinda does this but only vertically now?!)
3. The JPanel seems to assume the size of the JScrollpane regardless of what I set for preferred size

I am sure I'm doing something stupid, if someone could point out what I would be most grateful!

```
JPanel imageCanvas = new JPanel(); // 'Canvas' to draw on
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    
// set size of 'canvas'
imageCanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));

// Scroll pane smaller then the size of the canvas so we should get scroll bars right?
scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50,50)); 
    
// Add a border to 'canvas'
imageCanvas.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
    
scrollPane.setViewportView(imageCanvas);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

setPreferredSize() is the trick, setMinimumSize() and even setSize() on the component will be ignored by JScrollPane. Here's a working example using a red border.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Scroller extends JFrame {

    public Scroller() throws HeadlessException {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Scroller().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// suggest a size of 'canvas'
_ImageCanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

// Scroll pane smaller then the size of the canvas so we should get scroll bars right?
_ScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50)); 

// ..later 
_Frame.pack();
```

Comment: frame.pack(); re-loved it.

Answer (score 1):

- Set preferred size on the canvas.
- Increase dimensions 100,100 is too small atleast on my computer.
- You may want to use new GridLayout(1,1); for you JFrame if you want the scrollpane to expand when you expand the frame.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there are 2 options:

- define the preferredSize of _ImageCanvas
- create a subclass of JPanel and implement Scrollable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html

For more details, see the Javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

Comment: Hi Puce, thanks for the suggestions, turns out I needed to add a 'holder' jPanel to the scrollView and then give it a layout manager to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Scrollable` interface, this may help with the sizing issues.

These two method maybe helpful:

```
boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth();

boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight();
```