# JScrollPane: fixed width, automatic height

Tags: java, jscrollpane, border-layout

I'm using Swing for the first time and I've a problem with the JScrollPane...

I've this structure

> JPanel west
>
> > ScrollPane scrollPane
> >
> > > JList list

"west" contains "scrollPane".
"scrollPane" contains "list"

the "west" 's LayoutManager is a BorderLayout, now I want that the JScrollPane has a fixed width but the height adapts itself with the height of "west"...

Is there a solution?

Sorry for my poor english, but I'm not english and I'm very very sleepy :)

Comment: see setPreferredSize() - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9394139/763029

Comment: Try setMaximumSize() and set the width to what you want and the height to the screen height.

Comment: I'm tryed using setMaximumSize(), but the scrollPane remains at the minimum size

Using setPrefferedSize() I can set both width and height together, but not only the width... 

I'm missing something?