# How to add JScrollBar for Canvas?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

I have done MyCanvas class which extends GCanvas class, now I want to use and add this canvas another program, I have done this, but now I want to add scrollbar for canvas and  I have no idea how to do it, I have read some examples but it was difficult to understand, I would be grateful if someone will tell me :) ( I use java)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(MyCanvas);`?

Comment: NO, but what can I do then?

Comment: Add this line in the constructor of the component that has the JScrollPane.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393480/java-jpanel-inside-jscrollpane).